Why is my notarized and signed macOS .dmg rejected by Gatekeeper during installation?
I'm trying to distribute my macOS application (a .dmg file) to customers, and I've followed all the steps to sign and notarize the application. However, when I try to install the .dmg containing the app, Gatekeeper rejects it with the error "AppName cannot be opened because developer is not verified". Even though I’ve signed the app with my Developer ID, notarized it, and verified the signature using codesign, I am still encountering issues when attempting to install or open the app on a clean macOS environment. Here’s the error I see when using spctl to check the .dmg:
spctl --assess --type open --verbose=4 output/App.dmg
output/App.dmg: rejected
source=Insufficient Context

pctl -a -t open --context context:primary-signature -v ./output/Unbounded-0.0.1-arm64.dmg
./output/App.dmg: accepted
source=Notarized Developer ID

My .app is signed and notarised by electron builder and I explicitly signed and
notarised dmg too but still not working

Won't you need to sign it with an Installer certificate?
